# Calling multiple APIs that have the same value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, retrofit

I have a project that has two different APIs for a weather app.  One of the APIs gets the city information and the other API has the weather information.  They both have the same value called geonameid in their JSON response.  How do I go about calling the first API with the geonameid to lookup the data in the second API and how do I retrieve the second API's data from the geonameid value?

Comment: are you using Rx or kotlin coroutines

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh Kotlin coroutines

Comment: What relevance is it that the second api can return the geonameid? Does the second api have a way to request weather using this as an *input* rather than output? Not really sure what your question is without knowing what the APIs are. All we can tell you is to call the first api and then pass the result into your call on the second api.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The geonameid from the first api is acting as input to output information from the second api which holds the weather data and forecast data.  Both APIs have the same geonameid information.  I am trying to figure out how to link the two together.

Comment: Like I said, without knowing your specific APIs, all we can tell you is to call the first API, parse the JSON response to get the `geonameid` and then pass it into your call on the second API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make first call and wait for response from 1st API -> If the response is success -> Then extract value of geonameid and make a second call to 2nd API

Wrap it all in coroutines to synchronize two of that calls.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @RichardBroyles no since there is no code sample in your question